# Unexpected '[' in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

```
$p1 = "[0-9]{4}";
$p2 = "[0-9]{1,6}";
if($name == null || $id == null)
{
   // Assume that I have a error message set up
   die();
}
else if(!preg_match($p1,$id))
{
   die();
}
else
{
   //...Some stuff
}
```

I am receiving this when I try to submit my form:

> Parse error: syntax error, unknown modifier '{' on Line 29

(Line 19 is `$p1 = "^[0-9]{4}$";`.) Am I overlooking something or am I just being stupid?

Comment: Tip: use single quotes when writing regular expressions! If you ever have to escape anything, it’s a nightmare otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot your [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (and as minitech suggested, you should use single quotes in anticipation of future escaping problems).

Hence,

```
$p1="[0-9]{4}$";
$p2="[0-9]{1,6}";
```

should be

```
$p1='/[0-9]{4}$/';
$p2='/[0-9]{1,6}/';
```

which is the conventional delimiter. Note that you are free to choose from many different delimiter characters (see the link above), like

```
$p1='@[0-9]{4}$@';
$p2='@[0-9]{1,6}@';
```

This can be convenient, when your pattern includes `/`, so you don't have to escape them.